# The maximum number of elements of order 11 in a group of order 99

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Some people have already asked similar questions, but since most answers are based on Sylow theorems which I have not studied yet in class, I wonder if there is another way to solve the following question:

**What is the maximum number of elements of order 11 in a group of order 99?**

I know that by the Lagrange's Theorem, if $H \leq G,$ then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. This implies that the possible orders of the proper subgroups of our group are $\{1,3,9,11\}.$ I also know that if $G$ is cyclic, then I could use the Euler's totient function to determine the number of elements in $G$ that have the order 11, which, in this case, would be 10 elements. However, I am not sure if this is all I need in order to answer the question.

---

We've covered some properties of cosets and the theorem that states that for two finite subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group, we have that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H∩K|$, where $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H,k\in K\}$.

Comment: What else (in addition to Lagrange and Euler's totient in the case of cyclic groups) HAS been covered? Cauchy's theorem? Group actions? Those often lead to Sylow theory rather soon, but anyway. What about the formula for counting the number of elements of the form $hk$, with $h\in H$, $k\in K$ for some subgroups $H,K\le G$?

Comment: We've covered some properties of cosets and the theorem that states that for two finite subgroups H and K of a group, we have that $|HK|=|H||K|/|H \cap K|,$ where $HK=\{hk | h\in H, k\in K\}.$

Comment: Good. So you have figured out that ten elements of order $11$ is a possibility. What happens if $x$ and $y$ are two elements of order $11$ such that $y\notin H=\langle x\rangle $ and $x\notin K=\langle y\rangle$?

Comment: If "most answers are based on Sylow theorems" doesn't that mean that some answers are not based on Sylow theorems? What about those answers? Why not link to some of them?

Comment: You forgot possible order $33$. (Won't matter that much.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess that $x$ and $y$ generate two distinct cyclic subgroups of order $11$, and these two subgroups have $10$ distinct elements of order $11$. Therefore, when every element of order $11$ is in its own cyclic subgroup of order $11$, the maximum number of elements of order $11$ in a group of order $99$ would be $10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10+10 = 90$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that my statement is confusing :) I really only wanted to say that I have not found any answer which does not use Sylow theorems instead of claiming that there are no such answers out there. :)

Comment: @goykanpravi You can use result that you know about the order of the product $|HK|$ of two subgroups of $G$ to solve this problem without using Sylow's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an element $x$ of order $11$, then it generates the subgroup $\langle x\rangle$ where every nontrivial element is a generator of order $11$ either. On the other hand, two distinct subgroups $H$, $K$ of order $11$ are trivially intersecting (Lagrange), and hence they give rise to the set $HK$ of size $121$, a contradiction. So, there is at most one subgroup of order $11$, and hence at most $10$ elements of order $11$.